# How to submit form using ajax inside wordpress plugin

Tags: ajax, wordpress, plugins

I am creating small plugin where i want to submit form data using ajax but it giving response zero.

Here is my call i have added all code in a single file for the time being

file name :index.php

```
<?php wp_enqueue_script("jquery");?>
  <?php

   function myaddgallery(){
   global $wpdb;    
   echo "abac";

   }

   add_action('wp_ajax_myaddgallery' , 'myaddgallery');
   add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_myaddgallery' , 'myaddgallery');

   ?>
   <script type="text/javascript">
     jQuery(document).ready(function(){
     jQuery('#shaGalleryForm').submit(function(e){

         // prevent normal submit behaviour
    e.preventDefault();
     var name = jQuery("#shaGalleryName").val();
         alert(name);
          //var postData = jQuery("#shaGalleryForm").serialize();
          //console.log(postData);
          var name = "shalu";
          jQuery.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "http://localhost/plugindevelop/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
              data : {action: "myaddgallery", name : name},
              success: function(response){
                  //console.log(postData);
                  console.log("added success");
                  alert(response);
              },
              error: function(data){
                  console.log("fail");
              }
          });
     });
 }) ; 


</script>


<div class='wrap'>
    <h2>Add Gallery</h2>
    <p>This is where from you can create new gallery</p>
    <form name="shaGalleryForm" id="shaGalleryForm" method="post">
        <table class="form-table">
            <tr>
                <th>Gallery Name</th>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="shaGalleryName" name="shaGalleryName">
                    <p class="description">Add gallery name also please avoid special character</p>
                </td>

            </tr>


        </table>
        <p class="submit">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" id="shaSaveGallery" name="shaSaveGallery" class="button button-primary">
        </p>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Have a look at [**AJAX in Plugins**](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add die() after you echo the data

```
function myaddgallery(){
 global $wpdb;    
 echo "abac";
 die();
}
```